# Adding a Custom Expression in a Select array of Computers in AD

Tags: arrays, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to add a custom field in an array of computers searched for in AD.

This Variable has a list of computers that contains name and Description
$Computers

I want to create a custom field called 'newdescript' with the values as follows: Date moved from, and the computers DistinguishedName.
Like so:

```
$newDescript = "$(Get-Date) moved from $($Computer.DistinguishedName)"
```

Should appear like:

```
09/05/2022 11:16:18 moved from CN=PCNAME,OU=Some OU,DC=mydomain,DC=com
```

The code:

```
##New field at the end.  
$Computers | Select-Object Name, Description, newDescript

##newDescript must be = $newDescript
```

Output currently:

```
Name            Description           newDescript
----            -----------           -----------
PCNAME          Old Description       {}
```

Output should be:

```
Name            Description           newDescript
----            -----------           -----------
PCNAME          Old Description       09/05/2022 11:16:18 moved from CN=PCNAME,OU=Some OU,DC=mydomain,DC=com
```

Once I have the correct format I can then export it to csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2) to get the desired output:

```bash
$Computers | Select-Object Name, Description, @{
    N = 'newDescript'
    E = { "$((Get-Date).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')) moved from $($_.DistinguishedName)" }
}
```

The use of [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2) is not mandatory for this, it can also be done with a loop creating new [`PSCustomObject`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.2):

```
foreach($computer in $Computers) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name        = $computer.Name
        Description = $computer.Description
        newDescript = "$((Get-Date).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')) moved from $($computer.DistinguishedName)"
    }
}
```